# $a_1t^k\leq-\sqrt{1+x^2}+x\operatorname{arcsinh}{x}+1\leq a_2t^k,\ \forall\ t\in[0,\epsilon]$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Can we find constants $a_1,a_2,k>0$ such that $$a_1t^k\leq-\sqrt{1+t^2}+t\operatorname{arcsinh}{t}+1\leq a_2t^k,\ \forall\ t\in[0,\epsilon]$$

where $\epsilon>0$ is a small number?

Update 1: By using mathematica, it seems that $a_1=\frac{1}{3}$, $a_2=1$ and $k=2$ does the job, but I could not prove it until now.

Thank you.

Comment: $t$ and $x$ seem independent. I think this is a typo... can you update your question?

Comment: You are right @Ivan, I fixed it, thank you.

Comment: I gotta ask - did you try to plug in a series expansion?

Comment: No, I did not. Is the estimate that I proposed good? @ivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the series expansion it should be obvious that $\operatorname{arcsinh}{t}<=t$. Hence $$
-\sqrt{1+t^2}+t\operatorname{arcsinh}{t}+1\leq-\sqrt{1+t^2}+t^2+1\leq t^2
$$
so your RHS is obvious.

On the other hand your left hand side can be improved up to 
$a_1=\frac{11 - 6\sqrt{2}}{6}\approx 0.41912$

To see this, use the second term in the series expansion, i.e.: $\operatorname{arcsinh}{t}\geq t-\frac{t^3}{6}$. Hence $$
-\sqrt{1+t^2}+t\operatorname{arcsinh}{t}+1\geq 1+t\left(t-\frac{t^3}{6}\right)-\sqrt{1+t^2}$$ and prove that this is bigger than $a_1t^2$ using standard derivatives approach.

Thus, your inequality will hold in [0,1]. In fact if you need arbitrarily small interval, maybe any $a_1<0.5$ will do. I can't prove that yet though.